# Schema Comparison :: Create Schema [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]

Tags: visual-studio-2012, schema, authorization, sql-server-2012, schema-compare

When running a schema comparison between my Live DB (set as source) and DB Project (set as target) to ensure code is up to date with what's made it to production I'm seeing the following statement:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
    AUTHORIZATION [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
GO
```

I've set the option `ignore authorizer` but still see this.  Does anyone know what object type / option I'd need to enable or disable to prevent this item from showing up in comparisons?

Should it be of interest: My reason for wanting to remove this is I have a DB Project, not a Server Project, so don't have users included.  If I include this item I then get an unresolved reference the user; creating the user then gives me an unresolved reference to the login, and there I'd need the Server project to create it.  I don't want any login/user info stored in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to ignore "Schema" type objects in the comparison. I tried checking all "Ignore..." checkboxes and unchecking all "Object Types" - but Schemas are still compared.

However, I fixed this problem in my case by also including "Database Roles".

Answer (score 0):

What I do is that I select all the schema objects and Exclude them from the list.